# ASP.NET + Embedded Database + LinqToSQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

So I'm developing a new component that requires a little storage requirement. I don't want to use a full blown SQL Server database instance because it kind of defeats the purpose of this component. The first thing I tried was a Compact SQL Server database, but by default, ASP.NET does throws an exception if you attempt to use Compact SQL Server. I know also that you can override that with a line in the global.asax file, but I'm not sure if that is the right direction, as I am assuming Microsoft has a very good reason why not to let use this on ASP.NET by default. So I turned my attention to sqlite, but so far the only linqtosql library avaliable is Dblinq, which at this stage I'm not sure if it is production strength capable. So I guess what I want to ask is, is any of those options going to hold up for a commercial product? the embedded database is not going to be high transaction system, it is just to store some user information and that is pretty much it. Does anyone have experience with a situation like this? or Can you just recommend another embedded database linqtosql compatible?

Thanks! (and sorry for the long question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft have updated SQL Server Compact Edition to work with ASP.NET -
[see here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/30/new-embedded-database-support-with-asp-net.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

First, a question for you question: why are you so married to linqtosql?
You could use pretty much any data source and take advantage of linq via linqtoentity framework.
The best answer will probably depend on what you are trying to store and query.  I could think a simple xml file could suffice it the dataset is really small.